# Is Blizzard in violation of REGULATION (EU) 2016/679 for not letting users change their account real name?

Tags: european-union, video-games

When a player creates an account in battle.net Blizzard asks for your real name but many players registered when they were stupid little brats and wrote some pretty dumb things. The problem is that when you make a purchase, Blizzard issues an invoice to that name. However, Blizzard lets users change their name only in some very specific cases listed below. So by not letting users in the EU change their **incorrect** real name, is Blizzard in violation of **Article 16, Section 3, Chapter III of [REGULATION (EU) 2016/679](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/eli/reg/2016/679/oj)**:

> The data subject shall have the right to obtain from the controller without undue delay the rectification of inaccurate personal data concerning him or her. Taking into account the purposes of the processing, the data subject shall have the right to have incomplete personal data completed, including by means of providing a supplementary statement.

**Exceptions:**

1. You have changed your legal name
2. You are a parent or legal guardian who wants to take ownership of your minor child's account
3. You have reached the age of majority in your country and want to update the name of your account originally registered to your parent's name
4. You are claiming the account of a deceased relative